# Connection to mongodb atlas in codeigniter framework getting error

Tags: mongodb, codeigniter-3

What i am trying to do is to connect mongodb atlas with my codeigniter framework.

I have used this library for mongodb
https://github.com/verkhoumov/codeigniter-mongodb-library

Below is my connection code

```
$config['mongo_db']['default'] = [
'settings' => [
    'auth'             => TRUE,
    'debug'            => TRUE,
    'return_as'        => 'array',
    'auto_reset_query' => TRUE
],

'connection_string' => '',

'connection' => [
    'host'          => 'host link',
    'port'          => '27017',
    'user_name'     => 'username',
    'user_password' => 'password',
    'db_name'       => 'dbname',
    'db_options'    => []
],

'driver' => []
];
```

The main problem is mongodb atlas doesnt provide you the port its query string is like `mongodb+srv` not `mongodb:27017`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDb Atlas provides a connection string.
You can find it under Clusters -> Connect Your Application -> Copy a connection string.
Make sure to change "test" with your database name.
Then set it in 'connection_string' in your config file. Other parameters keep default.

```
$config['mongo_db']['default'] = [
    'settings' => [
        'auth'             => TRUE, 
        'debug'            => TRUE,
        'return_as'        => 'array',
        'auto_reset_query' => TRUE
    ],

    'connection_string' => 'mongodb://************@cluster0-shard-00-00-5ehze.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-5ehze.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-5ehze.gcp.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true',

    'connection' => [
        'host'          => '',
        'port'          => '',
        'user_name'     => '',
        'user_password' => '',
        'db_name'       => '',
        'db_options'    => []
    ],

    'driver' => []
];
```

Comment: already did not work, kindly go through the library once then answer, Thanks

Comment: the library and connection string working well for me. Please check that 'connection' parameter in your config has all empty values.

Comment: did you try with mongodb atlas, share your library code as well as config

Comment: yes, i use mongodb atlas where i got connection string, and i use same library https://github.com/verkhoumov/codeigniter-mongodb-library  I updated answer with example of config